# Visual Studio -> Code style preferences: severity of None is absent

Tags: visual-studio

In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019) I read about the severity:

[image]

But later on the same page I see this:

[image]

But the severity can't be None:

[image]

[image]

What is "None"? Is it "Refactoring only" or incorrect info?

Comment: None == Severity not set?

Comment: @RobertHarvey no. Severity always has a value.

Comment: That applies to the [editorconfig file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019#severity).  Accomplish the same in the GUI by clicking the glyph with the red x, removing the rule from the list.

Comment: @HansPassant that settings haven't the glyph with the red x - I added second screen with it.

Comment: Select the "Naming" node, it has the rules that can be None in editorconfig